# MySQL Insert a record based on a different table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

TABLE 1
userID | userName

TABLE 2
topicID | topicName

TABLE 3
userID | topicID
(One user can have several topics asigned)

I am receiving a string of topicNames and a userID. I need to insert this data into table 3 but first I need to get the topicIds from table 2. Currently my solution would be to do a select query to get the topicIds for the topicNames (from table 2) and then use that to insert to Table 3.

Is there a way to do the insertion and the mapping in one query?

Comment: What do the strings look like? If it's a comma-separated list of `topicNames`, you can use `FIND_IN_SET()` to match this against `table2.topicName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@string := 'topicName,userID';  -- for example, 'my super-topic,123'

INSERT INTO table3 (userID, topicID)
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@string, ',', -1), topicID 
FROM table2
WHERE topicName = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@string, ',', 1);
```

Comment: Thanks. INSERT INTO SELECT did the trick.